# SQL Subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a sql query but require explicit data from the database.

I have staged each query up to get the data i require.

```
SELECT wp_posts.id, 
       wp_posts.post_title, 
       wp_postmeta.meta_key, 
       wp_postmeta.meta_value 
FROM   wp_postmeta 
       LEFT JOIN wp_posts 
              ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'bolton' 
       AND wp_postmeta.meta_key IN ( 'address', 'age', 'cricket_club', 
                                     'training_times', 
                                     'location', 'player_type', 'coach' )
```

With this statement, It returns each row all together for address, age, cricket_club.

I require it though to get the value of address row rather than the meta_value row which lists them all.

Any advice is appreciated.

Further to this.

I dabbled with some code:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id = (
SELECT max( post_id )
FROM wp_postmeta )
```

However I want to get something like this.

```
SELECT address
FROM meta_value
WHERE wp_post_meta.meta_key = address
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post table structure , sample data and desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a suspicion that you want to *unpivot* your data, i.e. put different pieces of data into different columns. (I also suspect that on two occasions, when you say *row* in your question, you actually mean *column*, but that may be just me.)

If unpivot is really what you are after, then you could try the following method:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.post_title,
  MAX(CASE pm.meta_key WHEN 'address'        THEN pm.meta_value END) AS address,
  MAX(CASE pm.meta_key WHEN 'age'            THEN pm.meta_value END) AS age,
  MAX(CASE pm.meta_key WHEN 'cricket_club'   THEN pm.meta_value END) AS cricket_club,
  MAX(CASE pm.meta_key WHEN 'training_times' THEN pm.meta_value END) AS training_times,
  MAX(CASE pm.meta_key WHEN 'location'       THEN pm.meta_value END) AS location,
  MAX(CASE pm.meta_key WHEN 'player_type'    THEN pm.meta_value END) AS player_type,
  MAX(CASE pm.meta_key WHEN 'coach'          THEN pm.meta_value END) AS coach
FROM wp_postmeta pm
INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON pm.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.post_type = 'bolton'
  AND pm.meta_key IN ( 'address', 'age', 'cricket_club', 
                       'training_times', 
                       'location', 'player_type', 'coach' ) 
GROUP BY
  p.id,
  p.post_title
;
```

A couple of notes:

1. I replaced your LEFT JOIN with an INNER JOIN because the `wp_posts.type = 'bolton'` condition in the WHERE clause has essentially the same effect. If you really wanted a left join there, then perhaps you need to move the condition to the ON clause, like this:

   ```
   ...
   FROM wp_postmeta pm
   INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON pm.post_id = p.id
                        AND p.post_type = 'bolton'
   WHERE pm.meta_key IN ( ...
   ...
   ```

   But I'm not sure and you should see for yourself.
2. The other WHERE condition, `wp_postmeta.meta_key IN ( ... )` isn't necessary in this query in the sense that, although the query will read all meta keys, it will only return those for which columns are defined in the SELECT clause.

   Leaving the condition may make the query more efficient, but it will be slightly less convenient to extend the list of columns (in case you ever need to extend it): you'll have to extend both the condition and the SELECT clause.

   So, leaving the condition may be beneficial in terms of performance, and removing it may be better in terms of maintenance. When there are not many rows in the table, the difference in performance should be negligible, but whether it will be so in your case, you'll need to determine by testing. A general approach, though, is probably to go with a simpler solution first and optimise only as issues arise.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just change the

```
wp_postmeta.meta_key IN ('address','age',...
```

to

```
wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'address';
```

Comment: Hi, I require all the fields, address, age, cricket_club to be pulled, but as separate rather than as one block in the first select